# Django set bookmark for url querystring

Tags: python, django

I'm querying through some filters (django-filters) a list of *Book* objects, what I want to do is  save my research (aka my url with the GET params), creating a Bookmark object for the user.

**models.py**

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
```

**forms.py**

```
class BookmarkForm(BootstrapForm, forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Bookmark
        fields = ['nome', 'url']
        widgets = {
            'url': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

To do so I'm extending a CreateView and trying to pass current url to the initial valued of bookmark.url.

```
class AddBookmarkView(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'core.add_bookmark'
    template_name = 'core/bookmark_form.html'
    model = Bookmark
    form_class = BookmarkForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['url'] = request.GET.urlencode()
        return initial

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('elenco_libri')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        bookmark = form.save()
        bookmark.user = self.request.user
        bookmark.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

This doesn't get anywhere because I don't have the GET request in get_initial() function. Where could I store the url? I thought about the get() function but I don't know how.  Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have, it is at `self.request`.

Comment: inside get_initial, my self.request contains the path of the current view, which is AddBookMarkView mapped url. This is not what I want to save in my url field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This doesn't get anywhere because I don't have the GET request in `get_initial()` function.

Actually you have, the request object in a class-based view is an attribute: `self.request`.

So you can generate a URL with:

```
class AddBookmarkView(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'core.add_bookmark'
    template_name = 'core/bookmark_form.html'
    model = Bookmark
    form_class = BookmarkForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['url'] = self.request.GET.urlencode()
        return initial

    def form_valid(self, form):
        bookmark = form.save(commit=False)
        bookmark.user = self.request.user
        bookmark.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

The above will however, only give you the querystring. If you are interested in the path as well, you might want to use [**`request.get_full_path()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path%60).

You probably also do not want to save the object to the database in the `form_valid` function, so first obtain the bookmark, then set the `user`, and then save that object to the database.

Note that a `HiddenInput()` is rendered at the client side, and thus can be tampered with. Furthermore I'm not convinced that setting a bookmark through a form is per se necessary. You could construct a view that for example sets a bookmark with an AJAX call, and render a form with JavaScript to set the name and submit the bookmark.

Comment: If not in the form_valid() where is it ok to save the object in the database? It's not clear from your answer. I'll take in consideration AJAX for this task, I was trying to make it work the simplest way and then look for a more optimized solution.

Comment: @gccallie: no, we here save it by the `bookmark.save()`, but not in the `form.save()` since this will likely raise an exception.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you please help me with a similiar issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384218/how-to-bookmark-a-page-in-django